# Multiple select duplicate row issue

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, orm

I have some problem to many to many relation on form data. 
scenario is like
you can create new posts.There is select box in posts adding page.You can Select a few option. this is multiple selected. there is a many to many relation beetween tags table and posts table. and this relationship is recorded in the pivot table.

### Posts.class

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade =  {CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinTable(
        name="Posts_Tags",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="posts_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="tags_id")})
private Set<Tags> tag =  new HashSet<Tags>();
```

### Tags.class

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tag")
private Set<Posts> posts = new HashSet<Posts>();
```

---

This class is pojo class and it looks like associations(many to many)

When person want to create new item and select multiple tags then submit
the page says that ;

### ERROR !

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not 
execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [PRIMARY]

Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate 
entry '12' for key 'PRIMARY' at
```

### Post-add.jsp

```
<form:form class="form-horizontal" modelAttribute="post" method="POST" 
action="${contextRoot}/posts/add" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

---

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-8">
    <label class="control-label col-md-4" for="">Enter 
Description</label>
        <form:select path="tag" id="tag" cssClass="js-example-basic- 
multiple" items="${tags}"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

${tags} i sended tag items in list.And select box feature is multiple.

### PostMapping

```
@PostMapping(value = {"/add"})
public String adminPostSubmission(@SessionAttribute("User")User 
tempUser,@Valid @ModelAttribute("post")Posts post,BindingResult 
result,Model model,HttpServletRequest request) {
```

---

```
 postsService.saveOrUpdate(post);
```

How can I resolve this situation ?

Comment: add a new primary key with auto increment

Comment: I have got primary key each model